# Value of string resource is not displayed when passing it as a format argument to getString()

Tags: android, xml, string, kotlin

Following [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#formatting-strings), I have strings defined like this:

```
<string name="container">Hello %1$s</string>
<string name="content">World</string>
```

I'd like to display them combined into "Hello World", so I've tried the following code

```
myTextView.text = getString(R.string.container, R.string.content.toString())
```

but unfortunately the `content` string is always printed as a resource ID. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why this is happening is R.string.content is the reference id. What you need to do is nest that with `getString()` as well. That way it actually retrieves the string value instead of referencing as an Int.

```
myTextView.text = getString(R.string.container, getString(R.string.content))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve also your second string with the `getString` method:

```
myTextView.text = getString(R.string.container, getString(R.string.content))
```